# QAF - How To update junitreports.xml when running BDDStepFactory2

Tags: junit, testng, qaf

Im currently using QAF at my job and recently setup a few CICD tests using Azure Devops.

Azure Devops at the moment is only designed to read to Junit `.XML` results in their reporting dasbboard.

When running a Maven test, TestNG automatically creates a JunitReports folder that has a .xml report in it.

The issue is that when using QAF and using `BDDStepFactory2` in my `config.xml` file, my junit report shows all tests as ignored.

Is there a way I can continue using `BDDStepFactory2` and get the Junitresults to show either pass or fails?

EDIT:

The JunitResult is generating, however, this is what it looks like

````xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated by org.testng.reporters.JUnitReportReporter -->
<testsuite skipped="2" hostname=
name="com.qmetry.qaf.automation.step.client.DataDrivenScenario" tests="4" failures="0" timestamp="2021-12-27T16:21:34 EST" time="12.916" errors="0">
  <testcase name="Validate the Home Page" time="7.287" classname="com.qmetry.qaf.automation.step.client.DataDrivenScenario"/>
  <system-out/>
  <testcase name="Validate the Home Page" time="5.629" classname="com.qmetry.qaf.automation.step.client.DataDrivenScenario"/>
  <system-out/>
  <testcase name="scenario" classname="com.qmetry.qaf.automation.step.client.DataDrivenScenario">
    <skipped/>
  </testcase> <!-- scenario -->
  <system-out/>
  <testcase name="scenario" classname="com.qmetry.qaf.automation.step.client.DataDrivenScenario">
    <skipped/>
  </testcase> <!-- scenario -->
  <system-out/>
</testsuite> <!-- com.qmetry.qaf.automation.step.client.DataDrivenScenario-> ```

At the top, the xml is showing skipped="2". Since this is what Azure devops is reading, it is seeming like two of my tests have been skipped.
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably issue with TestNG version. Try latest ([7.4.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng/7.4.0)) version  of TestNG with latest ([3.1.0-RC1](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.qmetry/qaf/3.1.0-RC1)) version of QAF.

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>com.qmetry</groupId>
 <artifactId>qaf</artifactId>
 <version>3.1.0-RC1</version>
</dependency>
<!-- order is important -->
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
 <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
 <version>7.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

In order to write step information in junit report (just like testng reporter output) enable testng output by [setting property](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/different_ways_of_providing_prop.html).

```
report.log.testngoutput=true
```

Check your test-results directory, You may find junit report for each execution. For instance `<project-root>\test-results\<timestamp>\junitreports`. In case you don't found junit reports generated, you can enable testng default listeners.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not the issue. I'm using QAF 3.1.0-RC1 with TestNG 7.4.0. I am finding the Junit Report published, but all the steps are skipped.

Do you think the default testng listeners might fix this issue? If so, how can I implement them?

Thanks a ton!!

Comment: using latest version of testng will fix your original posted  **issue of all tests reported as ignored**. If you are looking for each step reporting withing testcase result, i am not sure that Junit xml report has provision for that. AFAIK junit reports test status (pass/fail/ignored) and error if any.

Comment: Sorry for the formatting. I'm new to stackoverflow.  This is what my pom file looks like. 

<dependency>
   <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
   <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
   <version>7.4.0</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.qmetry</groupId>
   <artifactId>qaf</artifactId>
   <version>3.1.0-RC1</version>
  </dependency>

Please let me know if that isn't enough to upgrade to TestNG 7.4.0

Comment: Regarding steps i just found that junit supports it trough `<system-out>` entry in xml. In order to enable that try setting  `report.log.testngoutput=true`

Comment: I really appreciate all your help!!! I Tried it, now I'm getting the output printed to the Junit report, but still showing skipped=2 at the top.

I have a total of 2 tests running as a part of this suite, but the Junit report shows 4. 2 passed, and 2 skipped.

Comment: refer updated answer

Comment: I figured out what the issue is. I am using scenario outline in my feature file, which is leading to the extra two tests being created in the Junitreport. When I use Scenario, I don't have this issue. Not sure what the move forward here since I pass my datasheet through the example tag which only works with scenario outline.

Comment: Alternate is create custom report implementation by implementing [IReporter](https://javadoc.jitpack.io/com/github/cbeust/testng/master/javadoc/org/testng/IReporter.html) or [TestCaseResultUpdator](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/javadoc/com/qmetry/qaf/automation/integration/TestCaseResultUpdator.html)

Comment: I actually got it to work. It was the TestNG version. Its working now even with Scenario outline. I just had to take a step back and clean up my pom file. I really appreciate your help!